# Module is not defined in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have this module that consists of AJAX functionality I'm looking to export to my Client Controller, but I'm getting Module is not defined, I'm using NodeJS and the Cloud9 Environment.

AJAX Module

```
module.exports = {
  appUrl: window.location.origin,
  ready: function(fn) {
    if(typeof fn !== 'function') {
        return;
    }

    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        return fn();
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
},
  ajaxRequest: function(method, url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.response);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
};
```

Client Controller

```
'use strict';

 var ajaxFunctions = require("../common/ajax-functions.js");

 (function(){

   var profileId = document.querySelector('#profile-id') || null;
   var profileUsername = document.querySelector('#profile-username') || null;
   var profileRepos = document.querySelector('#profile-repos') || null;
   var displayName = document.querySelector('#display-name');
   var apiUrl = ajaxFunctions.appUrl + '/api/:id';

   function updateHtmlElement(data, element, userProperty) {
       element.innerHTML = data[userProperty];
   }

   ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('GET', apiUrl, function(data){
       var userObject = JSON.parse(data);

       updateHtmlElement(userObject, displayName, 'displayName');

       if(profileId !== null) {
           updateHtmlElement(userObject, profileId, 'id');
       }

       if(profileUsername !== null) {
           updateHtmlElement(userObject, profileUsername, 'username');
       }

       if(profileRepos !== null) {
           updateHtmlElement(userObject, profileRepos, 'publicRepos');
       }
   }));
})();
```

Comment: Does the error message give any indication as to on which line the error occurs? Just a guess, I think you should check `var ajaxFunctions = require("../common/ajax-functions.js");` points to the correct location, and that `ajax-functions.js` exports a valid module.

Comment: Will do thanks, I'm getting an error on line 1 of the ajax-functions.js

Comment: Could you post that line?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at ajax-functions.js:1

Comment: I mean line 1 of `ajax-functions.js` :)

Comment: module.exports = {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to run the code in a browser, and the error you're getting is saying that `module` is not defined. If this code is intended to be run in a browser, you'll have to package it with Webpack or Browserify first.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't have its own `XmlHttpRequest`, which is something we take for granted in the web/browser world.  This is likely the cause of the errors in your AJAX module.  It is trying to reference a variable (`XmlHttpRequest`) which doesn't exist, and since it doesn't exist the file gets an error.

You *could* fix this by bringing in your own `XmlHttpRequest`, such as this one:
https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest.  To do this simply run:

```
npm i --save node-XMLHttpRequest
```

However, I'd recommend instead bringing in a `fetch`.  `fetch` is the new, cool, non-jQuery but still easy way of making AJAX requests, and it's supported by most browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch).  Just as with `XmlHttpRequest`, Node doesn't have its own version of `fetch`, but you can easily add it with:

```
npm i --save whatwg-fetch
```

The benefit of using `fetch` is that you'll have less "re-inventing of the wheel" to do vs. `XmlHttpRequest`.  You can learn more about `fetch` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API